# Read Fairbanks scale (Serial Device) input in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, serial-port, minicom

I need to read weight input coming from a Fairbanks 70-2453-4 scale. The machine is an old Dell Latitude D810 - it is docked (with a serial port) and running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr.

I have installed setserial and minicom... Output from `setserial -g /dev/ttyS*`:

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
```

Output from `stty --file=/dev/ttyS0 --all`:

```
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 5;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal crtscts
ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon
-ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0
vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop
-echoprt -echoctl -echoke
```

Minicom set-up is:

[image: minicom set-up]

Specs for data transmission are on page 16 of this manual:
[Fairbanks 70-2453-4 manual](https://www.fairbanks.com/documents/opmanuals/15159/50138.pdf)
[image: DataSpecs1]

Finally, `od -x < /dev/ttyS0` is throwing me a permissions error... And, I want to ultimately have the results returned through my LAMP stack using php.... Thanks for reading and any assistance.

Comment: First, note that the `stty` output says your serial port is set to `speed 115200 baud`, and the specifications say "`9600 baud`". Second, since `/dev/ttyS0` is owned by group `dialout`, add yourself to the `dialout` group `sudo adduser $USER dailout`, then logout/login. Third, doing `od` on a serial device is subomtimal. Investigate packages `expect - Automates interactive applications` or `expect-lite - quick and easy command line automation tool`.

Comment: Thanks for the notes... Yes, I am setting the baud rate with minicom as sudo... but, it doesn't seem to be changing the setting. I'll keep trying and will implement the others and get back to you. Thanks again :)